# Remove "edit", "help", "+add" in Control Panel

Tags: control-panel

I've created a Member Group and am trying to severely limit what members can access. All I want them to be able to do is to publish and edit certain Channels. So far, I have been able to implement that. However, I've noticed that the Control Panel has the following, too:

- "Edit" button: this is redundant as you can get to this UI by going to Content -> Edit. I'd like to remove this
- "Help" button: this takes the member to the EE site. I want this removed as I will provide my own help documentation
- "+ Add": I want this removed also; there is nothing for the member to do but to manage Channel entries for a few select Channels

Suggestions on how to do these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and easy answer, get your self ZFA:

- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin
- http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/flexible-admin

Note: I think the add-on description along with images in the links I provided are self explanatory and why I'm pretty sure my quick and easy answer is sufficient in this particular case.

Comment: I'll look into this. Does this give members certain features in CP? If so, I don't think that's what I want. I want to limit what member can do (configuring this stuff as a Super Admin).

Comment: Zoo Flexible Admin lets you have complete control over the CP navigation so you can build exactly what you want per member group. It will accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can create navigation based on member groups starting at Super Admin on down. It is however not for other parts of the CP, just the main nav. Giving access to certain parts of the CP will need to be done in each member group setting itself though, this is, IMO, one of the final pieces of the puzzle for a truly user friendly CP AND permission based access too at least in regards to the navigation and your initial question.

Comment: OK - this is sounding like a solid recommendation. Will look into it some more.